# Java GUI - General

Tags: java, user-interface, jbutton

Hello all you helpful folks @ stackoverflow!

Best resources for Java GUI's?

Looking at the Java Documentation, it is pretty easy to figure out the basics of JButtons, JFrames, etc but grasping the concepts of accessing JComponents from a frame, what creating a different panel does, etc is not very easy to understand.

Is there some tutorial that teaches the basics about Java GUI like swing and real-life examples?

Book suggestions are always welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm... Have you seen the [The Swing tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/index.html)?

Comment: Oh - I actually haven't, that looks good.

Any other resources? I find that "third-party" tutorials by independent developers make really good tutorials maybe because they are more practice?

definitely good to read from the source, first though.

Comment: I really dont know any better tutorial than this to learn Swing.
In addition I suggest to read this book: http://www.amazon.com/Swing-Second-Matthew-Robinson/dp/193011088X

Answer (score 1):

Once you've finished the [Swing Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/index.html), you should have a look at [Java Swing](http://books.google.com/books?id=cPxGfk-FZNUC&dq=java+swing&pg=PP1&ots=gFtz5Zntal&source=bn&sig=hKGpY7QtUTZrNjav41bPRuN4VcI&hl=en&sa=X&oi=book_result&resnum=4&ct=result).  It's a fairly comprehensive book.

Answer (score 0):

[java2s.com](http://www.java2s.com/) has good coverage of the [Swing library](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/Catalog0240__Swing.htm), including sample code for common tasks.

Answer (score 0):

For the technical stuff the Swing [tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) and after that the [Javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?javax/swing/package-summary.html) API documentation are enough for most people.

Getting a understanding on how to make a user interface that make sense the [Java Look and Feel Design Guidelines](http://java.sun.com/products/jlf/ed2/book/index.html) will be helpful.

Best tip I can give you is to get input from other people on your user interface. When you build *and test* an interface yourself your perception on what constitutes a logic and easy user experiences gets warped.

Answer (score 0):

I use SWT/JFace instead of Swing (for the native look and feel, primarily.)

[SWT/JFace In Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1932394273) has been the best resource I've found.

Additionally, the [SWT Widgets](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/widgets/) reference provided by the SWT project.